# Smartsheet API - OAuth flow - remembering authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, smartsheet-api

Once I've completed the OAuth flow by obtaining authorization from the user and then creating an access token, how do I obtain another token without asking the user for authorization again? I thought the user's account on Smartsheet would remember that they trusted the application, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm new to OAuth so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens retrieved via the OAuth flow are valid only for a certain period of time -- you (i.e., your application) can refresh a token before it expires in order to prevent the end-user from having to provide authorization again.

When you issue a [GET Token request](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#obtaining-an-access-token) to obtain an access token, the response contains not only the token itself, but also information to indicate how long the token is valid (the `expires_in` property indicates the number of seconds until the token expires) and a `refresh_token` property value that you'll need in order to refresh the token.

To prevent the user from having to provide authorization again, simply [refresh the token](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#refreshing-an-access-token) before it expires, and then use the new (refreshed) token value in subsequent API requests. Note that each token you obtain (whether it's the original token or a refresh token) will always expire in a finite amount of time, thereby requiring that you refresh the token in order for your application to maintain user authorization.

Comment: So what happens if the user doesn't use the application again before the token expires? Will I be unable to refresh the token?  Will they have to authorize the application again? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the token expires, it becomes invalid and cannot be refreshed -- the end-user will have to provide authorization again. That said, your application doesn't necessarily have to wait for the user to use the application again to refresh the token -- your application can refresh a token at any time (as long as the token hasn't yet expired).

Comment: @RobertSeger -- if my answer sufficiently addressed your question, can you please mark it as an "accepted" answer? Doing so will allow others to potentially benefit from the info in the future. Thanks!